# How to install Ruby on Rails 3.0 on Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

After installing Ruby and Ruby Gems:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ruby rubygems
...
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-06-23 patchlevel 299) [i686-linux]
$ gem -v
1.3.7
```

If I try to install Rails I get an error, and even though it seems to be the documentation only, `rails` isn't installed:

```
$ sudo gem install rails
...
Successfully installed rails-3.0.1
24 gems installed
... 
Installing ri documentation for builder-2.1.2...
ERROR:  While generating documentation for builder-2.1.2
... MESSAGE:   Unhandled special: Special: type=17, text="<!-- HI -->"
... RDOC args: --ri --op /var/lib/gems/1.8/doc/builder-2.1.2/ri --title Builder -- Easy XML Building --main README --line-numbers --quiet lib CHANGES Rakefile README doc/releases/builder-1.2.4.rdoc doc/releases/builder-2.0.0.rdoc doc/releases/builder-2.1.1.rdoc --title builder-2.1.2 Documentation
(continuing with the rest of the installation)
...
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.0.1...
File not found: lib

$ rails -v
The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rails
```

Ubuntu repositories only have Rails 2.3.5 so that isn't an option.

How do I get Rails to install properly?

**Update:** I tried the following, no error this time, but still no success:

```
$ sudo gem install rails --no-rdoc --no-ri
Successfully installed rails-3.0.1
1 gem installed
$ rails -v
The program 'rails' is currently not installed...
```

**Update 2:** So, thanks to Maran and Jörg, I now know the problem is not that `rails` isn't installed, but it's not added to the `PATH`. This can be fixed by adding the following to `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin:$PATH
```

That raises a further question: What should have added that to the `PATH`? Presumably the `apt-get install rubygems`? And what else may be broken?

Comment: As @jcm said, you really should look into using RVM. That is the quickest and easiest path to fresh Ruby and Rails goodness. RVM is all I'll use anymore because it makes life so much easier.

Comment: Why don't you simply use synaptic? It will install the main package with all uninstalled dependencies.

Comment: Not back in '11 it didn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I hesitated to use `rvm` as it seemed to be aimed at solving problems I didn't intend to have (multiple ruby versions? c'mon, I just want to play with rails...) and installing from source is generally something I want to avoid...

Anyway, I gave in and followed along with http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/

```
$ bash < <( curl http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-install-head )
```

Then (mostly suggested by the output of the above, but I needed to add `libmysqlclient-dev`):

```
$ sudo aptitude install build-essential bison openssl libreadline5 \
                        libreadline5-dev curl git zlib1g zlib1g-dev \
                        libssl-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 \
                        libxml2-dev libmysqlclient-dev
```

Then I edited my `.bashrc` as required and opened a new terminal.

```
$ rvm install 1.9.2
$ rvm --default use 1.9.2
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [i686-linux]
$ gem install rails
$ rails -v
Rails 3.0.1
```

After creating a new project, I still had a few things to do to make it work:

```
$ rails new myproject --database=mysql
$ cd myproject
$ emacs config/database.yml # set passwords
$ bundle install
$ rake db:create
$ rails server
```

And finally it all seems to be working. I hope that helps someone else, it certainly wasn't a particularly pleasant intro to a framework. I've reordered the commands I actually entered to avoid double handling for anyone following along.

Comment: Tried this on ubuntu 10.04.  I did: `rvm install 1.8.7`, then `rvm use --default 1.8.7`, then `rvm rubygems current`, and finally: `gem install rails`.  

It installed a bunch of stuff, but I then got:  
ERROR:  While generating documentation for builder-2.1.2  
... MESSAGE:   Unhandled special: Special: type=17, text="<!-- HI -->"  
... RDOC args: --ri --op /opt/standingcloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/doc/builder-2.1.2/ri --title Builder -- Easy XML Building --main README --line-numbers lib CHANGES Rakefile README doc/releases/builder-1.2.4.rdoc doc/releases/builder-2.0.0.rdoc [...]

Comment: @TrinitronX - i think it should be `rvm --default use 1.8.7`. Without that you're probably using the built in ruby and getting the same error as when i tried to install rails without rvm.

Comment: @Tom - Just tried that, then again ran `rvm rubygems current`... then 
`gem install rails` and got:  

Successfully installed rails-3.0.7
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.0.7...
File not found: lib
ERROR:  While generating documentation for rails-3.0.7
... MESSAGE:   exit
... RDOC args: --ri --op /opt/standingcloud/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334/doc/rails-3.0.7/ri lib --title rails-3.0.7 Documentation --quiet

If I run `gem --version`, it returns: 1.6.2

Comment: i'm out of ideas then i'm afraid... all i can say is the above instructions worked for me 6 months ago & hopefully someone who knows more about ruby can help you get going. good luck!

Comment: @Tom : Turns out there were some problems with rvm itself at the time I tried to use it!  Luckily, it appears the developer fixed them, so now it's working for me.  I also ended up needing to follow the [directions here](http://buzzcodington.wordpress.com/2011/04/29/file-not-found-lib-error-while-installing-rails-3-0-7/) and then retry via: `rvm gem install rails`

Answer (score 11):

I very strongly suggest you skip the Ubuntu packages and use [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/). The install process is pretty straight forward and [documented](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/). There is also a [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/200-rails-3-beta-and-rvm) on it.

RVM will allow you to install multiple versions and create custom gemsets (no dependency problems). It is WELL worth it and quickly becoming the de-facto way to develop (and deploy) with Ruby.

Answer (score 9):

http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/:

> Under no circumstance should you
>   install Ruby, Rubygems or any
>   Ruby-related packages from apt-get.
>   This system is out-dated and leads to
>   major headaches. Avoid it for
>   Ruby-related packages.

Answer (score 3):

try installing the rdoc gem first:

```
gem install rdoc
```

It worked for me using RVM on ruby 1.8.7 and  rails 3.0.7

Good luck.

Comment: I had the same issue as the original poster of this question while trying to install Ruby 1.8.7-head + rails 3.0.7 via rvm on Mac OSX 10.7.4. 'gem install rdoc' fixed the error for me.

Answer (score 2):

The Debian version of RubyGems installs Gems into `/var/lib/gems/1.8/` and Gem binaries into `/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin`. You need to make sure that directory is in your `$PATH`.

This is a typical example of what I call the "If you hear hooves, think horses, not zebras" rule. If a computer tells you it cannot find something, the first thing to look for, is if that something is actually there, the second thing is whether the computer is looking in the right place. Installing `libreadline5-dev` OTOH is pretty far down the end of the list …

In this case, you are telling the computer to execute the file `rails` in the `$PATH`, which simply doesn't exist, because the directory it was installed into is not in the `$PATH`.

Comment: You may want to be a bit more explicit, i.e. add "export PATH=/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin:$PATH" to your ~/.bashrc

Comment: @Tom: How you manage your `$PATH` is your business, not mine. I, for example, prefer to set it in `/etc/environment` and not in `~/.bashrc`, but that is just my personal preference, and I wouldn't want to impose it on anyone. In fact, you don't need to add it to the `$PATH` *at all*, you could just call it as `/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/rails` or create an `alias rails=/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/rails` or whatever. It's really your choice (and doesn't have anything to do with the question anyway).

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing rails is installed just fine but the gem-folder is somehow not setup in your PATH. Do a search somewhat like this `find / -name *rails* | grep bin` and check if that yields any results; if so check if the path rails is located in is also in your PATH. (echo $PATH)

Comment: Spot on, it's in /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/rails and /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rails-3.0.1/bin/rails

Comment: That find command is messy though, `find / -name *rails* 2>/dev/null | grep bin` is more manageable.

Answer (score 0):

I documented the process I went through.  It covers git, rvm, and vim.

http://appogee.posterous.com/ubuntu-1010-ruby-on-rails-setup

Answer (score -1):

You will need a bunch of building tools.  Googling "install rails 3.0.1 ubuntu" and you will find the info.  It will be something like:

```
apt-get install curl git-core build-essential zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libreadline5-dev
```

Also recommended is RVM, which is very good for having multiple Ruby versions and different gem sets, good for experimenting and for using different versions of Rails on the same machine.

Comment: rvm also makes compiling rubies extremely simple

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't help. I was only missing git and libreadline5-dev and I don't understand why they wouldn't be dependencies of rubygems if they were needed by it?

Comment: I remember one page didn't help but trying another page and it worked...  maybe some info was for Rails 3.0.0 beta.  Also... maybe rubygems doesn't directly depend on it, but some of the gems it build require those tools.  There are also many gems that don't require the build tools

Comment: How the heck did this get upvoted? It doesn't have anything even remotely to do with the question.

Comment: don't you need build tools to install Rails and some other gems such as sqlite3-ruby or mysql2?