# rails installation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After I run

> sudo gem install rails --version 3.0.7

for installing rails on Mac. It got some errors.
Could anybody help me how to solve it?

```
Successfully installed rails-3.0.7
24 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for activesupport-3.0.7...
Installing ri documentation for builder-2.1.2...
ERROR:  While generating documentation for builder-2.1.2
... MESSAGE:   Unhandled special: Special: type=17, text="<!-- HI -->"
... RDOC args: --ri --op /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/doc/builder-2.1.2/ri --title Builder -- Easy XML Building --main README --line-numbers lib CHANGES Rakefile README doc/releases/builder-1.2.4.rdoc doc/releases/builder-2.0.0.rdoc doc/releases/builder-2.1.1.rdoc --title builder-2.1.2 Documentation --quiet
```

Comment: Looks like it's just a problem building the local-machine documentation for one of Rails' dependencies. Did the installation continue? Does the gem work?

Comment: yeah, it works. Looks like just documentation issue here. If can fix it, it would be better. :)

Comment: You might want to check the answers to this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151768/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-3-0-on-ubuntu-10-10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you won't need that documentation anyway, so:

```
sudo gem install rails --version 3.0.7 --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the  Rdoc/ri documentation, you will need to install a later version of version of Rdoc/ri.  The solution [is documented here](http://buzzcodington.wordpress.com/2011/04/29/file-not-found-lib-error-while-installing-rails-3-0-7/):

To quote from Mr. Okwaro, 
"... first uninstall the Rails version you just installed with no Rdoc/ri data:

```
sudo gem uninstall rails –version 3.0.7
```

Install the latest version of the rdoc-data gem. This will install ri data for core and stdlib:

```
gem install rdoc-data
```

Then run:

```
rdoc-data –install
```

In case you want rdoc-data for all your gems run (not necessary.. takes a while if you have as many gems as i do):

```
gem rdoc –all –overwrite
```

To install ri data for RDoc 2.5+ run:

```
rdoc-data
```

Now you can install your Rails version and it will successfully install all the rdoc-data too.

```
sudo gem install rails
```