# Rails installation issue; Shows up in the list of gems but does not show version number

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, installation, rubygems

I have been trying to install Rails using the installation guide provided in railstutorial.org.

After going through the process, when I type `rails -v` the following results come up

`The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rails`

But when I enter `gem list rails` it shows:

` *** LOCAL GEMS ***

rails (3.0.1)`

I don't understand the problem. How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `bundle exec rails -v`

Comment: I solved the issue using the solution given in the following question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151768/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-3-0-on-ubuntu-10-10

Thank you for helping!